# get process handle by PID

Tags: delphi

I want to get the handle of a process by the process name.

I have PID but when I use `openProcess` to get the handle always it will return 0 or 180, the function that I use to get the PID working properly

`Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ,False,PID);`

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you inspecting the handle value?  This is not a cross-process value, this is generated by the OpenProcess API.  180 is possibly simply a valid handle to the opened process.  Did you attempt to use the handle other than to determine its numerical value?

Comment: I want to get the handle  i didn't find  any solution to get it directly

Comment: i just want this,get the handle of a process by it's name

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to get a process handle when all you know is its name, unless you're using `CreateProcess`.

Instead, you can use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489.aspx), [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834.aspx), and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836.aspx) to search for all processes having the name you want. Keep in mind that there may be multiple processes with the same name. Those functions will tell you the process ID. Once you have that, you can use `OpenProcess`, as you've already demonstrated. If `OpenProcess` returns something other than zero (such as 180), then it has given you a valid process handle.

Comment: U means the process handle is not unique ? so 2 process that are runinng may have two PID and  one handle?

Comment: I don't know how you reached that conclusion from what I wrote in my answer. Anyway, a process may have many handles open for it. You could call OpenProcess twice on the same PID, and you should get two different numeric values — two handles, one process. You could call OpenProcess on the same PID from two different programs, and you might get two different values, or you might get the same value in each program, but those are still two different handles.