# Slow down a Windows Process?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, process

How can I slow down a Windows Process?

I understand that I need to hook `QueryPerformanceCounter` but what do I need to do next?

Need help for Delphi or C++

Comment: Is this just for your own program or for any program?

Comment: Do you want to slow down a game which uses queryperformancecounter to determine its speed, or do you want to slow down a calculation intensive process?

Comment: @casablanca : any program i know how to inject a dll is not a problem

Comment: @CodeInChaos a game check cheat engine

Comment: Well the just hook the function used to time the game(queryperformancecounter, gettickcount and the current time are common) and manipulate it's result so it increases more slowly than realtime.

Comment: And why don't you just use the speedhack.pas you posted yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the relationship of hooking QueryPerformanceCounter to slowing down a process that you described. Perhaps if you elaborate in the original question or a comment, I can help you further.

To answer your question, you can use cpustres.exe from the Windows 2000 resource kit to put a load on your system, causing context switching. If you put enough of a load and oversubscribe all available CPUs, you will slow down your process. Depending on the load level you select with the cpustres settings, you can slow your process down a lot or a little.

If you want to slow down the process programmatically in a more controlled way without crashing it if it is a game, you can use casablanca's answer, but replace Sleep(10) with:

```
// Turn off optimizations to make sure the busy wait loops do
// not get optimized out!

HANDLE hThread = ...; // thread that you want to slow down 
for (;;) { 
  SuspendThread(hThread); // Do this for each process thread

  // Busy wait for pause (possibly small)
  const DWORDLONG pauseFactor=1000; // In cycles
  DWORDLONG start=__rdtsc();

  while (__rdtsc()-start<pauseFactor)
    ;  

  ResumeThread(hThread); // Do this for each process thread

  // Busy wait for resume
  const DWORDLONG runFactor=1000; // In cycles
  DWORDLONG start=__rdtsc();

  while (__rdtsc()-start<runFactor)
    ;  
}
```

Comment: rdtsc is even more problematic on multicore processors than queryperformancecounter, so using it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: rdtsc works perfectly on i7 processors and is even synchronized across the four cores on a single CPU (and runs at the highest P-State, so there is no frequency drift with SpeedStep and Turbo). I am not sure if this is true for Core 2, so some testing may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to have a dedicated thread use [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the thread that you want to slow down, wait for a little while and then resume the thread:

```
HANDLE hThread = ...; // thread that you want to slow down
for (;;) {
  SuspendThread(hThread);
  Sleep(10); // some number of milliseconds - larger values will slow down more
  ResumeThread(hThread);
}
```

Comment: i've tryed that and it crashes the target application ( is a game ).It works slowing down with cheat engine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the motive/background of your question since you didn't explain it clearly. However, using `SetPriorityClass()`, you can sets the priority class for the specified process to `BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` or even to `IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS` so that the process running slower; and you can also sets the priority class for the specified process to `ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` or even to `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS` so that the process running faster. Before doing that, you'll need to get handle of target process by its PID, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150869/get-process-handle-by-pid).

Comment: This doesn't make the process faster or slower.  It just changes the possible allocation of CPU cycles to the process.  If no other processes need CPU cycles (e.g. processes are sleeping or blocked), then the priority class doesn't do anything -- the process will "burst" to use whatever CPU cycles are available, until another process with higher priority needs the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2000 introduced a new layer over internal process management that allows to set extra limits on one or more processes: Jobs. I'm not sure if it allows to set a limit on processor time used, but if the application isn't using the method already, you might just be able to call [AssignProcessToJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [SetInformationJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to impose extra limitations.