# Delphi Get the handle of a EXE

Tags: delphi

Heres an example of how I'm doing it right now :

```
var
Client : String;
Handle : Integer;
begin
Client := 'Window Name';
GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);
Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);
end;
```

I'd rather grab the  Process's handle with its exe name...
Is this possible this?

Comment: What "handle? The window handle (HWND), the module handle (HMODULE), or some other handle?

Comment: the window handle (HWND)

Comment: Then, I must also ask: "What window?" A single application (EXE) can contain a lot of windows, some of which might even be invisible (not even forms). The "main" window or the (invisible) "application" window?

Comment: It really doesn't matter I'm reading memory with ReadProcessMemory...and instead of grabbing a handle of any window with the application id rather grab the handle with the exe name because every window that is opened by the EXE has a different name...

Comment: OK, so the handle you really do need is actually a *process handle*, not a window handle.

Comment: And what do you have *already* that you can use to get the process handle? If you only have EXE name, then there can be multiple copies of EXE running, and ... ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150869/get-process-handle-by-pid for similar question -- the answers there apply to your question as well.

Comment: there will only be 1 copy.. running and what im using right now is {GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(Client)), @ProcessId);}

Comment: i could make a function to parse window names and look for certain a string in the window name.. but id rather not do that even though it wouldn't be hard...

Comment: if you need a process handle then call EnumProcesses

Comment: Yep, EnumProcesses or EnumWindows as that can take a Window class instead of a Window title. The class of the IDE's main window for example is TAppBuilder. Once you have the handle of a window in the process, the process handle should be easy to find, but EnumProcesses is probably a lot easier and more direct.

Comment: @Worm: I am afraid that I have to agree with Bryan here. In fact, most of your comments here at SO (only counting the ones I have seen) are actually of the same kind, implying stuff like "God, this ignorance kills me!" For your own sake, if for nothing else, you might consider recalibrating your attitute generator. Just saying...

Comment: See link in my post. It is incredible library which let You ability to get any info about your system (including processes)

Comment: @Abelisto if only i could read german..

Comment: My English is much worse than my German )

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to post my own answer....which isn't the way I want to do this but I guess I'm going to have to...

Comment: @Bryan: Abelisto's link not pointing to a German page. I think it is Spanish.

Comment: @Bryan: are you trying to cheat on this poker game?

Comment: At the right side of the page you will see the button "translate".  
Unfortunately I don't need this functional for my current projects for now, so I can not make my opinion about this library. But Demo is impressive.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, please dont make me highlight some of your posts. For own sake. And cease mangling my nickname please.

Comment: @Bryan, a) your original post was "How to retrieve HDUNNO from unclear thingie there" making endless thread of cross-questions to figure out what you really want; b) you edited it effectively making Abelisto's answer useless and having him to return and seek for additional clues for you.

Comment: BTW, Platform SDK have useful sample on enumerating processes and retrieving image filenames.

Comment: @worm @andreas complaining about being called worm is silly. You gave yourself that name. If you don't like it you have nobody to blame other than yourself. You are at liberty to change it.

Comment: @Bryan "crawl in a hole and die please" is exceedingly offensive. Yes @Worm's comment wasn't constructive or even intelligible, but your response is even worse.

Comment: Funny! :)))   
Lets return to the question: Ho to obtain EXE name by window handle.  
I think it is clear described in the MSDN.  
As homework try to find that ))

Comment: @David Heffernan, you again... I'm not calling you stupid, but i told you twice already. Now come on, dont be that lazy and learn to use copy and paste commands. Or pay a visit a local bar and enjoy being surrounded by Joe, Moe, Heh and Meh. Ignoring your further attempts from now on.

Comment: Sorry, no any attempt. Just describe your task in all and we will try to explain how to realize it.

Comment: As I understand, the questioner trying to manipulate by another program. Without any knowledge in Delphi, C, Java & API except Basic.  
Yes, I haven't any idea ho to answer except link to the site for novices (if exists)

Comment: @Abelisto Well, bad luck then. WinAPI is quite harsh to newcomers who got used to object wrappers with exceptions. Have to check almost every return value and read tons of documentation (which, thankfully, is quite good and detailed)

Comment: No any needs to read or know whole API. Enough to know what to say for question.  
Ok, anybody know how to get handle by "*.exe"? And anybody know for what?  
In any case I provide link to library whitch provide needed info. Any other talks is just rock. I don't against that but moderators and owner of the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ProcessInfo](http://www.mediafire.com/file/lleoal6xpry6mh3/ProcessInfo+v1.5.zip):

```
var
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInfo;
  Process : TProcessItem;
  PID: Cardinal;
  ProcessHandle : THandle;
begin
  ProcessInfo := TProcessInfo.Create(nil);
  try
    Process := ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses.FindByName('Notepad.exe');
    if Assigned(Process) then
    begin
      PID := Process.ProcessID;
      ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,PID);
      if ProcessHandle > 0 then
      try
        {Add your code here}
      finally
        CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
      end;
  end;
  finally
    ProcessInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you do not like using a third-party component, you can study source code of ProcessInfo to see how it retrieves list of running processes, and their properties. Basically it relays on Windows Tool Help API for most of its features.

Answer (score 5):

Since the link provided by vcldeveloper is broken, here's the full function code that works without 3rd party components.

First we will find process id (PID), and then we'll get process handle by opening all access (since the OP mentioned in the comments he will need this for ReadProcessMemory functionality).

If the function for PID returns 0, it means that the process is most likely not running (or just not found in the running process list)

```
function GetPIDbyProcessName(processName:String):integer;
var 
  GotProcess: Boolean; 
  tempHandle: tHandle; 
  procE: tProcessEntry32;
begin
  tempHandle:=CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0); 
  procE.dwSize:=SizeOf(procE); 
  GotProcess:=Process32First(tempHandle, procE);
  {$B-} 
    if GotProcess and not SameText(procE.szExeFile, processName) then 
      repeat GotProcess := Process32Next(tempHandle, procE); 
      until (not GotProcess) or SameText(procE.szExeFile,processName); 
  {$B+}

  if GotProcess then 
    result := procE.th32ProcessID 
  else
    result := 0; // process not found in running process list

  CloseHandle(tempHandle);
end;
```

Next, we will get/open Process handle from the PID we got. The whole code/usage is as follows:

```
var myPID, myProcessHandle: integer;
begin
  myPID:=GetPIDbyProcessName('someExeName.exe');
  myProcessHandle:=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,myPID);
end;
```

You should store the `myProcessHandle` in such way that it is accessable for    
 `ReadProcessMemory(myProcessHandle...)` as first parameter.

Also, add these to your global uses clauses: 
`Winapi.Windows` (for ReadProcessMemory and OpenProcess) 
`Winapi.tlHelp32`(for getting PID tProcessEntry32 variable)

Answer (score 4):

`Application.Handle`?
Looks like you're trying to program in Delphi by WinAPI. In the vast majority do not need it, VCL provides appropriate object-oriented wrappers.
May be You will find something in this component pack: [GLibWMI](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?page_id=578)

Comment: I got the feeling the OP isn't looking for the handle of the own application.

Comment: No.  
Unfortunately I haven't installed WinAPI help for now. But You can try to get help starting from API function `EnumProcesses` for example

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand  
Its look like that @Bryan trying to write virus on Delphi.  
Just a joke. Sorry for offtopic.

Comment: @Abelisto @Bryan is attempting to write an online poker bot using SendKeys

Comment: @Abelisto, you should edit or remove your answer, because in the new light it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Abelisto: "installed" WinAPI help? What is wrong with MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @David I'm not attempting I have and sendkeys is only for bet ammounts >.>

Comment: @David posting a image in a sec

Comment: Comment deleted.  
@Andreas Rejbrand I using WinAPI help from Delphi5 at work. At home I using Delphi 2011 and I haven't any help files installed for it (for technical reasons).  
I know what is MSDN and I know where I can find it ))

Comment: @bryan i still hope you get your just desserts and lose all your money when your bot bets on the wrong hand!!

Comment: I think it's not the words that you have to say.  
In Russian community exists perfect site deplphikingdom.ru  
I hope, in English community exists site like this with section for novices.

Comment: @Bryan That image you posted shows that your code still does not have any indentation. Are you aware of the fact that you are lacking in almost all of the fundamental skills of a programmer? If you were to listen to some of the good advice you have been offered here by any number of expert programmers, you would improve. You have enormous room for improvement. Do you even want to improve?

Comment: how does it not have indentation explain?if there was a word wrap type thing in delphi where you could make it all pretty like id use it...

Comment: also whats the point of flaming someone that is new to coding..this is one of my first major projects... and it doesn't help that the last project i was working on was over a year ago..I only got back into coding because a friend of mine that uses delphi alot wanted me to get back into it so we could work on stuff...

Comment: and I'm sorry I'm not ocd about how my code looks ... all i do is comment it really...

Comment: @bryan I'm not flaming. I'm talking about indentation not wrapping. Do a websearch to learn about it. Look at my answer to your question about the if statement. You would be far less likely to make such mistakes if you indented your code. Look at other people's code. Try to learn better ways of doing it.